# I can not use env file variable values in my node project

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have 2 variables in env file. For Port and mongoDB link. I have tried many solutions on the  internet but i am not able to access the values in the listen method nor in database connection.
Here is my sever file code:

```js
const app = require("./app");
const connectDatabase = require("./config/database");

// Config
require("dotenv").config({ path: "backend/config/config.env" });

// Connecting to database
connectDatabase();

app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is working on http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`);
}); // I can run the app if i use any port number in place of "process.env.PORT"
```

[image: You can see folder structure plus the variables in my env file]

Note: I have put the wrong password here to hide my credentials.

I have tried to use env file in root directory also but it did not resolve the issue. The thing is i can access the values in the console but not in the listen method or in connection method.

I can run the app with direct values.
[image: App working fine with direct values]

Here is the listen method error screenshot:
[image: console error for the port]

Comment: The server is crashing because it is trying to listen on port `3000;` which is not a valid port number, not because it can't read the envs. You have `POST=3000;` in the envs file.

Comment: If i do this, i can run my app. That's not port issue app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log(`Server is working on http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}`);
});

Comment: here is screenshot link. I have changed the value of PORT to 4000. https://paste.pics/H2Q60

Comment: The question was very clear, I dont know why anyone would down vote it. Yes, the title could've been better but people need to tell the newbies rather than just downvote them and not say what was wrong. +1

Comment: Thanks, @DushyantBangal for understanding my question and taking the time to answer it.

Comment: @DanishShabbir — You haven't changed it to `4000` you've changed it to `4000;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you are passing `3000;` to the `listen` function, you need to pass `3000`.

Remove the semicolons `;` from the env file and it should work.

Have a look at the dotenv npm page [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) for examples.

Also, you have posted your mongodb credentials online, I'd suggest you change those immediately.

Comment: That's not the case. I have already mentioned i can access the values in the console log.  I have removed underscores but it still gives error.

Comment: Thanks for your concern Dushyant Bangal. I know that, that's why i have put wrong password there.

Comment: sorry, I mean semicolons. I see in your latest screenshot, its still there. `4000;` instead of `4000`

Comment: remove the `;`. Your first line should be `PORT=3000`

Comment: Thankyou Dushyant Bangal for your help. You are right . It was a semicolon issue. Thanks mate. I was trying every solution available on the internet but i was not seeing the semicolon. Please give vote to my question also.

Comment: Please don't answer questions where the solution is "Fix the typo". This type of question has no long term value since other people with the same problem are not going to find this by searching. "Typo" is one of the standard Close Vote reasons. Answering this type of question can block the OP from deleting it to remove bloat from StackOverflow. You can delete this answer to remove the possibility of blocking such clean up.

Comment: @Quentin while I agree with you on the typo, I believe this is a syntax issue. The OP didnt put the `;` by mistake, they thought it was needed and it was the syntax. Many people might make that same mistake in the env file (including myself the first time I used it). So I think this would be helpful for people who are not using the right syntax.